# Using PHP i want to find 2 numbers whose sum is in the array

Tags: php

I want to Find 2 numbers whose sum is in the array.

`$arr = [1,2,5,3]`

output should be 3 and 5

2+3=5  and 1+2=3

below is the code which i have tried.

```php
$input = array(1,2,5,3); 
$length = count($input) - 1;
$count = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= $length; $j++) {
        if ($input[$i] + $input[$j] == 0) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

echo $count;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution below, searches for a all the sums starting from each number seperately. You can search for larger sums, by increasing $numbers_of_sum.

```
    $initial_array = array(1,2,5,3);
    $numbers_of_sum = 2;

    search_for_sum($initial_array, $initial_array, 1, $numbers_of_sum); // recursive call

    function search_for_sum( $initial_array, $sums_so_far, $counter, $stop_counter ){
        foreach($sums_so_far as $sum_number){
            $new_sums = array();
            foreach($initial_array as $number){
                $new_sums[] = $sum_number + $number;
            }

            foreach($new_sums as $sum){
                if(in_array($sum, $initial_array))
                    echo $sum.' is a sum of numbers in the array.<br>';
            }

            if(($counter+1)!=$stop_counter)
                search_for_sum($initial_array, $new_sums, ($counter++), $stop_counter); // recursive call
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Over engineered, and the result is wrong. it includes 2, but also duplicates 3 and 5. In addition, it takes twice as long as the answers given by @Martjin

Comment: This is a general solution. It includes the results of @Martjin and searches for more combinations.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You're missing an `in_array()` check:

```php
$matches = [];
for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= $length; $j++) {
        $sum = $input[$i] + $input[$j];
        if (in_array(sum, $input)) {
            $matches[] = $sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this logic will become very slow very fast if you increase the size of `$input`. Every N items extra will result in N*N extra iterations.

Bonustip: A foreach makes this easier to read:

```php
$matches = [];
foreach( $input as $outerValue ){
    foreach( $input as $innerValue ){
        $sum = $outerValue + $innerValue;
        if (in_array($sum, $input)) {
            $matches[] = $sum;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I'm on a little roll: Based on a hunch, this might be faster for larger sets as it performs way less `in_array()`:

```php
$sums = [];
foreach( $input as $outerValue ){
    foreach( $input as $innerValue ){
        $sums[$outerValue + $innerValue] = 1; // use key to avoid duplicates
    }
}
$sums = array_keys($sums);
$matches = array_intersect(array_unique($input), $sums);
```

For giggles I benchmarked the options:

```
1. double for + in_array: https://3v4l.org/FHZ7v/perf
PHP     time    mem (mib)
8.2r    0.068   19.45
8.1     0.074   19.68
8.0     0.073   18.83
7.4     0.077   18.41

2. double foreach + in_array: https://3v4l.org/uV5Xq/perf
PHP     time    mem (mib)
8.2r    0.095   19.59   
8.1     0.095   19.64   
8.0     0.093   18.89   
7.4     0.094   18.40   

3. double foreach + intersect: https://3v4l.org/ncWDk/perf
PHP     time    mem (mib)
8.2r    1.998   19.88
8.1     1.989   22.58
8.0     1.988   21.82
7.4     error
```

My solution wasnt fast at all. Every day you learn. I'm sure this is improvable, but not today ^_^

Comment: Hi Martijn thanks for your help, Can you please help to get numbers in place of counts

Comment: The `foreach` version does something different than the `for` version! The `for` version will output 3 and 5, and the enhanced `foreach` version will output 2, 3 and 5. 2 because of 1+1.

Comment: Somewhere my brain switched to multiple instead of add. Updated accordingly, and now keep track of the matches

Comment: This is a very interesting problem. The initial input does not even begin to suss out the potential algorithmic issues in the problem. Try this input instead: `$input = array(1,2,5,3,7,10,15,6,14); `. In this case, even though the `for` version runs about twice as fast, it duplicates 7 and 15!

Comment: I missed an array_keys, now it works